# Transfer large amount of data from text file to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, file, data-transfer

I need to set up automated process to transfer large amount of data, apparently millions of rows from a flat file to SQL Server. I know we can do it using Java IO libs but that will be very slow. What other options are there for a faster execution?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous closed question. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was a .sql, then I would suggest using the sqlcmd file to import it.  If it isn't in that format, then you can reading a large file in parallel in c#, using a blockingCollection, which is also cool since you can restrict how many threads will be doing the import, you could even have logic which would get the number of cores etc and then from there decide on the number of threads if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, there is separate tool bcp.exe available for this purpose. This is the fastest way to insert data into table.

[Read more on bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

Simple example on loading a tsv file (default format for bcp is tsv)

```
bcp.exe DBName.SchemaName.TableName IN "C:\inputFile.tsv" -c -T -S "TargetServerName"
```

If you want to using tsql route, you can go for `BULK INSERT` command. You need to first generate format file & later use `BULK INSERT` command to insert into the table.

```
BCP DBName.SchemaName.TableName format nul 
-x -S ServerName -c -f C:\inputFileFormat.xml-t, -T
```

```
BULK INSERT DBName.SchemaName.TableName
FROM "C:\inputFile.tsv"
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\inputFileFormat.xml');
GO
```